# PHP COUNT_RECURSIVE giving wrong output for an associate (hierarchical) array

Tags: php, arrays

And thank you for any help you can provide ...

I have an associate array (hierarchical) created through PHP from a mySQL database. I am running on a shared-server platform so I am restricted to using mySQL version 5.6.46 which means I do not have access to "recursive CTE" and "WITH" commands. What I am trying to accomplish (with PHP) is to calculate the exact number of children (not just the first level but all levels below) and Concat that number to the end of EACH person's name in this organization hierarchy. After several hours on Stack Overflow looking for ideas on how to make this work, I found very little reference to this exact issue but I've been able to extract enough code to come up with something that is "partially" working. The frustrating part is not knowing why it works correctly for the root level but not for the levels below. Could someone please let me know what I'm missing in my code and which direction I should head? Thank you!

Here is an example of the output of the associate array. As additional information, there are exactly 72 children/grandchildren for the root.

```
[
  {
    "value": "Jim Smith [VP]",
    "id": "10003",
    "items": [
      {
        "value": "Michael Jones [Senior Director]",
        "id": "10004",
        "items": [
          {
            "value": "Ralph Henry [Director]",
            "id": "10012",
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "Michael Peterson [Manager]",
                "id": "10046",
                "items": []
              },
              {
                "value": "Bryan Gosse [Manager]",
                "id": "10048",
                "items": []
              },
              {
                "value": "Sally Eichart [Manager]",
                "id": "10053",
                "items": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "value": "Mike Walsh [Director]",
            "id": "10016",
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "Kevin Michaels [Manager]",
                "id": "10033",
                "items": []
```

Here is what I am getting when I run my code:

```
[
  {
    "value": "Jim Smith [VP] (72)", //correct!
    "id": "10003",
    "items": [
      {
        "value": "Michael Jones [Senior Director] (3)", //should be (19)
        "id": "10004",
        "items": [
          {
            "value": "Ralph Henry [Director] (0)", //should be (3)
            "id": "10012",
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "Michael Peterson [Manager] (0)", //correct (but is it?)
                "id": "10046",
                "items": []
              },
              {
                "value": "Bryan Gosse [Manager] (0)", //correct
                "id": "10048",
                "items": []
              },
              {
                "value": "Sally Eichart [Manager] (0)", //correct
                "id": "10053",
                "items": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "value": "Mike Walsh [Director] (0)", //should be (4)
            "id": "10016",
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "Kevin Michaels [Manager] (0)", //correct
                "id": "10033",
                "items": []
              },
```

Here is my code:

```
public static function getTopCategories()
    {
        $prime_id = $_SESSION['email_address'];
        return self::getCategories('email_address = "' .$prime_id. '"');
    }

public static function getCategories($where = '')
    {
        if ($where) $where = " WHERE $where";
        $db = Database::getInstance();
        $mysqli = $db->getConnection();
$sql_query = "SELECT CONCAT(primes.first_name, ' ', primes.last_name, ' [', domains.position_root, ']') value, domains.prime_id AS id, domains.mgr_id FROM domains INNER JOIN primes ON domains.prime_id = primes.prime_id $where";
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql_query);

        $categories = array();

        while ($category = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $my_id = $category['id'];
            $category['items'] = OrgChart::getCategories("mgr_id = $my_id");
                $categories[] = $category;
                $countChildren = (count($category['items'], COUNT_RECURSIVE) / 4);
        }

        foreach ($categories as &$value) {
            $value['value'] = $value['value'] . " (".$countChildren.")";
        }
```

Comment: No one has any idea what I'm doing wrong in my code? Would appreciate some thoughts on where to focus with this. Thank you!

Comment: Hello. I have valued from all of the resources available on Stack Overflow as I learn PHP and mySQL. So I'm stymied as to why no one has any ideas on how to solve my posted question. I am new to 'asking' questions on SO so maybe I'm not doing it right? I've attempted to provide all of the pertinent details but no input from the community. I notice most of the resources I'm finding on SO (previous questions asked by others) are dated. Perhaps something has changed and no new questions are being answered? Could someone fill me in? Thank you!